# Adding google maps to webpage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I want to create one webpage with one textbox, one button and one div containing the google map. My use case is whenever I enter some address in textbox and click on the button the google map for that place should get rendered in that div. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

and either the geocoding service:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

or autocomplete:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

The samples linked there should give you plenty of code to draw on.

Comment: The first example in the Geocoding service link provided in this answer: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple is exactly what you're looking for.